# Different sha512 output for same string in swift

Tags: string, swift, sha512

I'm trying to figure out why I get different SHA512 string for the same given string in swift.

I used a class in Obj-C for transform string in sha512-string.

her's the code:

```
-(NSString*)sha512:(NSString*)string{

NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (int)data.length, digest);
NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

NSString *string512 = [NSString stringWithString:output];

return string512;
```

}

in swift I simple call the method like this

```
println(encryption_password().sha512("z"))
```

every time, i get different print in console.
Any ideas?

thanks so much

Comment: *Hint:* CC_SHA1 is not CC_SHA512.

Comment: My god, it was so simple!!! Really silly mistake, thanks